# netsh suddenly stopped working - now cannot load IFMON.DLL

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, batch, netsh

The following commands recently stopped working on my system

```
netsh interface ip add dns name="Wireless Network Connection" addr=8.8.4.4 index=1
netsh interface ip add dns name="Wireless Network Connection" addr=8.8.8.8 index=2
```

Both die with the complaint that the helper `DLL IFMON.DLL` cannot be loaded.

I tried running

```
netsh add helper IFMON.DLL
```

and that fails with the same complaint.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `sfc /scannow` from an elevated command prompt.